# How to remove all php.INFO logs from Symfony 4 logs in production?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, monolog

I'm struggling to configure monolog properly.

I keep receiving these messages in my /var/logs/prod.log

> 2020-04-02 18:26:01] php.INFO: User Deprecated: Using the "templating" service is deprecated since version 4.3 and will be removed in 5.0; use Twi....
>
> [2020-04-02 18:26:01] php.INFO: User Deprecated: The "twig.exception_listener" service is deprecated since Symfony 4.4. {"exception":"[object] (Err...
>
> [2020-04-02 18:26:01] php.INFO: User Deprecated: The "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener" class is deprecated since Symfo....

Despite setting up the minimum level to error, it only seems to work for app.* type of logs and not php.*

Here is my prod/monolog.yaml

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: fingers_crossed
            action_level: warning
            handler: nested
            excluded_http_codes: [404, 405]
        nested:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: warning
        console:
            type: console
            process_psr_3_messages: false
            channels: ["!event", "!doctrine"]
        deprecation:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.deprecations.log"
        deprecation_filter:
            type: filter
            handler: deprecation
            max_level: info
            channels: ["php"]
```

And in my framework.yaml I also have this bit of code:

```
framework:
    php_errors:
        log: true
```

Thank you

Comment: your `deprecation_filter` config has `max_level: info`. Try setting that to `max_level: warning` or `max_level: error`

Comment: Hi Alex, yes I did try to set it to error but it didn't chance. This bit of the code relates to another file prod.deprecations.log that does the job just fine.